# Deep Learning, Strange batch normalization

Tags: keras, deep-learning, batch-normalization, dcgan, generative-adversarial-network

The below is my Generator structure.
As you see, if I remove the batch normalization, GAN extremely works well.
But if I add Batch Normalization at the commented place, it shows only noise.

I don't know why. I have tried add BN to generator only or discriminator only or both too.
Even when I add only one BN layer into anywhere, it never works.

I am trying to fix the source at git https://github.com/rickiepark/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/8.5-introduction-to-gans.ipynb

I know it is explained with KOREAN that you guys are not easy to understand but it's very simple source for keras text book.

```
Dense(128 * 16 * 16)
LeakyReLU
Reshape((16, 16, 128))
Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same')
LeakyReLU
Conv2DTranspose(256, 4, strides=2, padding='same')
# BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)
LeakyReLU
Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same')
# BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)
LeakyReLU
Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same')
layers.LeakyReLU
layers.Conv2D(3, 7, activation='tanh', padding='same')
```

Comment: self answer: found that the result is nan when batch norm is used.